# Windows Vista cannot find firefox.exe

Tags: windows, windows-vista, firefox

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox>firefox
The system cannot find the file C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe.

C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox>dir
 Volume in drive C is ACER
...
26/10/2010  10:10 PM           912,344 firefox.exe
```

Tried registry clean then a Firefox reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Check registry `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Window NT\Current Version\Image FIle Execution Options\firefox.exe`
If you find this key, delete it.

It is possible that your computer is/was infected with virus.